# F.Promise<Result> and nested async promises

Tags: java, playframework

I am using F.Promise in my async action in Playframework 2.4.6. I am able to get async calls to my DAO to work. I am able to use "map" and "flatMap" but I am not sure about the following situation.

I have an async call to find and object from the database. If that object is found, I then want to use parts of that object to then issue another async request to update that object in the database. This is part of an async update call in my controller. I am not doing something right though.

I am starting off with the following.

```
F.Promise<User> findUserPromise = userService.findAsync(id);
F.Promise<User> updateUserPromise = userService.updateAsync(updatedUser);

F.Promise<Result> resultPromise = findUserPromise.flatMap((foundUser){
    // update foundUser with passed in Json criteria
    foundUser.firstName = firstName; // etc...

    return updateUserPromise.map((updatedUser) -> {
        return ok(Json.toJson(u));
    });
});

return resultPromise;
```

This doesn't seem to work. I do not want to define my updatedUserPromise until I get a response back from my findUserPromise, because maybe a user will not be found. If a user is not found, I will return F.Promise.pure(notFound("some json result")). If a user is found, then I want to update that user with the Json criteria that gets posted to my controller action. With my approach, it seems that I have to define the updateUserPromise's async call with an object (updatedUser) before I get back any results.

Can I define another promise inside the result of a promise?

I was thinking something like this, but this fails with compilation errors. inference variable B has incompatible bounds, equality constraints: play.mvc.Result, lower bounds: Play.libs.F.Promise.

```
F.Promise<User> findUserPromise = userService.findAsync(id);

F.Promise<Result> resultPromise = findUserPromise.map((foundUser) -> {
    // foundUser is returned, now update it, or return not found...

    // define our next promise with an updated foundUser object
    F.Promise<User> userPromise = userService.updateAsync(foundUser);
    F.Promise<Result> resultPromise2 = userPromise.map((u) -> {
        return jsonResult(ok(Json.toJson(u)));
    });
    return resultPromise2;

});

return resultPromise;
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: shouldn't you do `flatMap` too on `findUserPromise` ?

Comment: Maybe I had it all along, but I was using something incorrectly. Thanks for replying.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is best way to do this, but this is working for my situation above.

```
F.Promise<User> findUserPromise = userService.findAsync(id);

return findUserPromise.flatMap((fu) -> {

    if (fu == null) {
        ObjectNode result = Json.newObject();
        result.put("error", "Not found " + id);
        return F.Promise.pure(jsonResult(notFound(result)));
    }

    // dynamically update fields on found user
    fu.userName = userName;
    fu.firstName = firstName;
    // more updates...

    // make a new promise that will use the updated foundUser object
    F.Promise<User> updateUserPromise = userService.updateAsync(fu);

    return updateUserPromise.map((uu) -> {
        return jsonResult(ok(Json.toJson(uu)));
    });
}
```

All the examples I found for chaining promises or nested promises, they seem to use web services as an example, and they all appear to be known at design time. In my situation, I do not know what my foundUser object will be until it is returned, so I need to create my inner promise inside the outer promise.